# Why does using a method to define a new method not work?

Tags: javascript, methods

I don't know why this code doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

```js
String.prototype.splitb = function () {
  this.split('b') 
}
console.log('aba'.splitb())   \\❌
console.log('aba'.split('b')) \\✅
```

Comment: You forgot to `return` from your function. (Voting to close as caused by typo / other trivial issue unlikely to be of use to future visitors).

Comment: how do you define a trivial issue unlikely to be of use to future visitors?

Answer (score 1):

You should return from your method:

```js
String.prototype.splitb = function () {
  return this.split('b') 
}
console.log('aba'.splitb())  
console.log('aba'.split('b'))
```